# Converting an image from RGB to CMYK with Node JS

Tags: node.js, node-modules, rgb, color-space, cmyk

My printer only work on CMYK colors. And I want to make a telegram bot with node js.
I searched on internet to directly transform image color space. But I cannot find.

For python; I find Image.convert(). Its worked for me.
My question is that can I make this with an node package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this awesome npm package called Sharp
https://github.com/lovell/sharp

Installation is:

```
npm install sharp
```

Then your JS is as easy as:

```
const sharp = require('sharp');

console.log('Converting...')

sharp('input.jpg')
    .toColourspace('cmyk')
    .toFile('output.jpg')
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Conversion completed!')
});
```